# Runtime Error in Trying to Paste from One Excel Workbook to Another

Tags: excel, vba

I used to get this error once in a while, but now I get it every time I run my macro:

Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)':
Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

Essentially, what I have tried to do is to copy data from a large personal excel workbook to an Excel workbook on the Sharepoint.  I do this through a third helper spreadsheet.  This helper spreadsheet (set as the ActiveWorkbook) successfully opens both Excel sheets, and does some error checking before copying and pasting the data.  But now, it won't save to the Sharepoint... here is the block of code the debugger stops at:

I have the helper Workbook set as the active Workbook.  I tried to set SPwkbk as the active Workbook, but this causes Excel to crash.

I added the FileFormat := 1 tag for the .xlsx on the Sharepoint, but this seems to have had no effect.

I thought about saving to one worksheet at a time (personal worksheet and Sharepoint have identical names for sheets), but thought this would make the program slower than it already is...

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
SPwkbk.SaveAs Filename:=SPwkbkPath, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, _
        ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
SPwkbk.Close                                                          
myWkbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I know that it copies and pastes correctly as it has worked before... but I do not understand what is preventing it from saving, even when there is no person editing/viewing the file on the Sharepoint.  What could be causing this?

Comment: This code neither copies nor pastes. It saves the file with the [`SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) method (Click for link.)  Just a guess: perhaps saving in "exclusive mode" is related to the problem.  Also, it's not a good idea to disable [`DisplayAlerts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts) until everything is debugged.  Beyond that, you'd need to figure out/clarify what you're trying to do before anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at the end the file format i think that is why is throwing an error.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

.SaveAs Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName, 55 'file type for addins extension
```